# Backbone js has no method Extend

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have started with backbone today and having hard time get it loaded as it returns the error as

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){var c,d=a||
{};this.cid=f.uniqueId("c");this.attributes={};b&&b.collection&&
(this.collection=b.collection);b&&b.parse&&(d=this.parse(d,b)||
{});if(c=f.result(this,"defaults"))d=f.defaults({},
d,c);this.set(d,b);this.changed={};this.initialize.apply(this,arguments)} has no method   
'Extend'
```

which actually means that it has no method called Extend.

**Code**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        Wine = Backbone.Model.Extend();
    })(jQuery);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

No idea on what is the actual problem behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the e on `extend` capitalized. It should be:

```
Wine = Backbone.Model.extend();
```

Capitalization is everything!

Comment: my gosh , this is what happen when a newbie starts with a new library.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have the `e` capitalized, should be `extend`:

```
Wine = Backbone.Model.extend();
```

[extend](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend)